# mac osx how to use emacs with .rst file

Tags: aquamacs, mac, rst-mode

use emacs 28.1 on my mac osx 14.5. I would compile restructured text file but I obtain error. CAn someone tell me the exact command I've to type to obtain it?

I mean: what do I need to compile rst file other that emacs?

Comment: When you say "compile": compile to what?

Comment: I mean: compile the .rst file to obtain HTML or .PDF

Comment: Please don't post the same question on emacs.SE and on StackOverflow. Choose one to keep and delete the other. Thx.

Comment: [Sphinx](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/)? I added the same comment to your SO duplicate question: you can see why duplicate questions are not useful. Heed @Drew's comment and delete one of them.

Comment: ok, Ive deleted the SO duplicate question. I've duplicate it because I've found  this place after I've posted on SO.
anyway...any sudgestion?